# How can I use same EJB in two different CDI beans and retrieve the values set from one bean into the another?

Tags: ejb, cdi, stateful

I have a stateful session bean where a list is maintained:

```
@Stateful
public class CartDAO{

    private List<ShoppingCart> tempCart;
    public void add(ShoppingCart shoppingCart){
        tempCart.add(shoppingCart);
    }

    public List<ShoppingCart> getCart(){
        return tempCart;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        tempCart = new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

Controller1 to add to the cart:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class Controller1 implements Serializable {
        @EJB
        CartDAO cartDao;
        public String addToShoppingCart() {
        cartDao.add(shoppingCart);
        }
}
```

Now, i want to ask you could i get the added items to the list from another cart?

```
 @Named
    @SessionScoped
    public class Controller2 implements Serializable {
            @EJB
            CartDAO cartDao;
            public String getShoppingCart() {
            System.out.println(cartDao.getCart());//returns null
            }
    }
```

Obviously the above code returns null.

How do I retrieve the list from another controller. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you *really* mean null, or do you mean that the list is empty because Controller1 and Controller2 each have a unique instance of CartDAO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any obvious mistake here (are you sure that you don't call `Controller2#getShoppingCart()` before adding any items do your `CartDAO`?) but here are couple of my notions

- you should have your `CartDAO` implement some interface or make it `@LocalBean`
- all stateful beans should have method annotated with `@Remove` so you can clean the resources used in the bean (close datasources and son) and bean will be removed from the memory after this call
- now it's recommended to use `@Inject` everywhere instead of `@EJB`, it's the same (you have to use `@EJB` only when you inject remote beans)

And also one point, if the `System.out.println(cartDao.getCart());` returns null than it means the `@PostConstruct` haven't been called which is strange. Can you provide some more info about container and your environment?Also show us imports, this is big source of mistakes.

Comment: Solved using @Inject annotations